# Download and check target not defined for luac

Tags: android, c++, c, lua, vlc

I compile [vlc-android](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/), throw this message in terminal:

```
ABI:        armeabi-v7a
API:        android-16
SYSROOT:    /media/danixt/linux/danxit/android-ndk-r11c/platforms/android-16/arch-arm
PATH:       /media/danixt/linux/danxit/android-ndk-r11c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91/bin:/usr/lib/gradle/gradle-2.11/bin:/media/danixt/linux/danxit/Android/Sdk:/media/danixt/linux/danxit/Android/Sdk/tools:/media/danixt/linux/danxit/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/media/danixt/linux/danxit/android-ndk-r11c:/media/danixt/linux/danxit/android-studio/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
CFLAGS:            -g -O2 -fstrict-aliasing -funsafe-math-optimizations -mlong-calls
EXTRA_CFLAGS:      -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -I/media/danixt/linux/danxit/android-ndk-r11c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -I/media/danixt/linux/danxit/android-ndk-r11c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
Building tools
You are ready to build VLC and its contribs
Building the contribs
Generating EGL pkg-config file
Generating GLESv2 pkg-config file
Guessing build system... x86_64-linux-gnu
Creating configuration file... config.mak
Bootstrap completed.
Run "make" to start compilation.

Other targets:
 * make install      same as "make"
 * make prebuilt     fetch and install prebuilt binaries
 * make list         list packages
 * make fetch        fetch required source tarballs
 * make fetch-all    fetch all source tarballs
 * make distclean    clean everything and undo bootstrap
 * make mostlyclean  clean everything except source tarballs
 * make clean        clean everything
 * make package      prepare prebuilt packages
 * make help         show this text
Makefile:506: *** Download and check target not defined for luac. stop.
contribs: make fetch failed
```

---

Version: `lua -v`

> Lua 5.2.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio*

Version: `luac -v`

> Lua 5.2.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio*

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

1.download tarball from [lua](http://www.lua.org/versions.html#5.1)
lua-5.1.5.tar.gz (don't use 5.2.4， it is not complete)

2.make lua

```
cd lua-5.1.5/ 
make linux
```

3.install lua

```
make linux install
```

finished!!!